# Displaying number of notifications in the Title for every Stack Exchange site

Tags: feature-request, notifications

We all love notifications, either is for a new reply to your comment or you have a new answer or you just received couple of new badges. But it's really hard to follow them with all these new Stack Exchange sites that are launching every few hours and you have them all open in different tabs.

It would be a great feature if we could see the number of notifications in the Title, so you could click on the tab to see what happened there.

For example:

- Stack Overflow (2)
- Web Apps (1) - Stack Exchange
- Meta Stack Overflow (5)

Answer (score 3):

I completely **agree**, expect that I think that titles should be in the following format:

- (1) Stack Overflow
- (5) Meta Stack Overflow

This way, it's easy to see how many notifications you have by just looking at the beginning of the title. Putting the numbers at the end of the title would become a problem with long site names.

Comment: I choose the other format because the site's name is more important than the notification number.. check how Google Reader does it or Gmail (and it's better to enable the Title tweaks from Labs)

Comment: I thought they do it with the number first... plus, it doesn't completely cover up the site name (unless you're someone with a ton of notifications). Good point though. :)

Comment: someone like @Jon Skeet for example.. :D