# Facebook notification style (3), etc. in the window title

Tags: feature-request, notifications, window-title

Facebook puts a little `(1)` in the page title whenever you have a comment, etc. I find this really handy when I have a bunch of tabs open, and it would be great on Stack Overflow too. So, could we get the development team to add this in?

To clarify, when a notification or comment is received and shown as a number in a red/blue circle next to the Stack Exchange logo in the top bar, I think it would be a good idea to mirror that number in the page title, similar to the way Facebook does.

Comment: This already happens in chat. Not sure whether it's really applicable to SO proper, though

Comment: It is already added to the StackExchange logo on the left hand side of the SE bar, but this would be useful if it is updated using out-of-band javascript so the title is updated without causing the whole page to refresh.

Comment: @Mark Hurd - yeah that would be handy. The reason for wanting it in the title is so that when one has loads of tabs open, for example, we can instantly see if there is a new message or whatever :-)

Comment: @JamWaffles I am missing this feature so much :( Even one year down the line, nothings added of this kind

Comment: When browsing a specific tag, the [live-refresh feature add's numbers to the title of the page for new questions in that tag](http://i.imgur.com/qtPxt.png).  How would you suggest solving the conflict between those numbers and the number relating to notifications that you are proposing?

Comment: @Lix Good point. The notification number could be put in square brackets or something, but that would make the title pretty messy. I'm not sure how useful the tag live-refresh feature is to users (although personally I don't use it) so it could be removed if nobody uses it.

Comment: Related - [Can we get notification in the tab (change of title)?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57315/can-we-get-notification-in-the-tab-change-of-title?rq=1).  Includes [an answer containing a user-script to get this functionality](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65202/172936)

Comment: [More](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66712/poll-in-background-for-stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown-inbox-events?rq=1) possible (older) dupes  - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57590/displaying-number-of-notifications-in-the-title-for-every-stack-exchange-site?rq=1.  This was before the live-refresh was implemented though...

Comment: Has this really not been added in yet? I somehow remember seeing `(x)` in the tab, but I can't actually find out now since there isn't much activity.

Comment: @Purmou. It exists on the homepage of sites when new questions appear, and I think on tag pages too. But this is for any new questions on that page. It's unrelated to your personal inbox. I can't think of any sensible way to get both into a title bar. Perhaps instead of numbers, a simple * could be used to show either type of notification.

Comment: @TRiG: The reason I would love this is because I use a Chrome extension that adds a little notification count to the favicon, but requires that the page's title have the count in parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of notification exists, but is being used for a different purpose. On the front page for each site (except SO due to large volume), the title will notify you when a question has been updated.

[image: (1) Meta Stack Overflow]